# Getting response after posting to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I tried testing my code written to post data to mongodb via postman using x-www-formurlencoded but I keep getting this error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Not Found</h1>
            <h2>404</h2>
            <pre>Error: Not Found
    at Layer.app.use.res.render.message [as handle] (c:\Users\Tomix\Documents\Source\Tomix\app.js:39:15)
    at trim_prefix (c:\Users\Tomix\Documents\Source\Tomix\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:226:17)
    at c (c:\Users\Tomix\Documents\Source\Tomix\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:198:9)
    at Function.proto.process_params (c:\Users\Tomix\Documents\Source\Tomix\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:251:12)
    at next (c:\Users\Tomix\Documents\Source\Tomix\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:189:19)
    at next (c:\Users\Tomix\Documents\Source\Tomix\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (c:\Users\Tomix\Documents\Source\Tomix\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:150:14)
    at next (c:\Users\Tomix\Documents\Source\Tomix\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at Function.proto.handle (c:\Users\Tomix\Documents\Source\Tomix\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:234:5)
    at Layer.router (c:\Users\Tomix\Documents\Source\Tomix\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:23:12)</pre>
        </body>
        <!--Live reload script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
    </html>
```

So what am trying to do is to create an e-commerce website with mean stack,so am trying to structure the app files and folder to reflect the server side and the client side.
The code here is to save data to database (mongodb), but from the error message I was able to deduce is that at the point it ought to return response in json format it throws the error message.

```js
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  console.log('I got called', req.body);

  var product = new Product(req.body);

  product.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {

      return res.send(400, {
        message: err
      });
    } else {

      res.json(product);
    }
  });
};
```

My app.js file

```js
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

/*connecting the to database*/
require('./config/db');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
app.use(cookieParser());



app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
        next();
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
    next();
});

//Routes
require('./app/routes/product.server.routes.js')(app);

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Please am stuck have search online for possible solution, some of the suggestion I got was I need to add method-override to my express configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed a part of the equation:

Post/Info -> Connector/Driver -> Mongodb/Database

Yo can not post JSON to mongo via Postma. You'll need to find a mongodb solution for javascript to play with it. You can try it with Node.js for example. Here I give you a list of all the language possibilities to connect to mongo.

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Am sorry not to have mentioned that am using mongoose as my mongodb driver; further more the data actually gets saved into the database but I don't get any response after its been saved. Thanks